# Why I cannot access controls in HeaderTemplate of a gridview in SqlDataSource_Selecting event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a simple gridview with one column called "State", and a DropDownList in it's Header to set a filter:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        Please Login
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="AssetsID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AssetsID" HeaderText="AssetsID" SortExpression="AssetsID" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">State</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Not used</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Using</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Gzone %>" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" SelectCommand="DisplayAssets2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </LoggedInTemplate>

</asp:LoginView>
```

and behind code:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = this.User.Identity.Name;

        GridView g = (GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1");
        DropDownList d = (DropDownList)g.HeaderRow.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        string s = d.SelectedValue;
        e.Command.Parameters["@State"].Value = s;
}
```

But I don't understand why I can't access the DropDownList1 with this code, it's value is null.

Thanks
Paddy

Comment: Not tested, but my guess is that the `OnSelecting` event is called before the data is send to the GridView. Therefore the GridView is not yet filled with data and will return null.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback VDWWD, I think my DropDownList1 is filled with 3 value manually by myself, it should working, I don't know...But I really need it's value to set the @State parameter.

Comment: Yes, but you want that data in an event that takes place before grid databinding. You need the grid to be binded with data to be used in the method that selects the data that needs to be bound to the grid. See the impossible loop here?

Comment: OK, I can't do this filter in this event, so I change a way to do it with the same result: [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2   Thank you very much, VDWWD.

Comment: Place the DropDownList outside the GridView.